# PartialFunction in Scala

Tags: scala, partial-functions

I am looking at the `PartialFunction` source code of Scala. In the file,  the trait `PartialFunction` as well as a companion object `PartialFunction` are defined. The companion object has methods `cond` and `condOpt`.

Link: https://github.com/othiym23/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala

When I look into `andThen` as well `orElse` function, the below method calls are present.

```
1. PartialFunction.this.isDefinedAt(x)
2. PartialFunction.this.apply(x)
```

I am not sure from where these functions (isDefinedAt / apply) are present.

Can someone please help where these two methods are present.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the official code is at https://github.com/scala/scala, not the fork that you mention

Answer (score 3):

`apply` is defined on [`Function1`](https://github.com/othiym23/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Function1.scala#L33), the parent class of `PartialFunction` (Note that `A => B` is syntax sugar for `Function1[A, B]`). `isDefinedAt` is defined directly on the [`PartialFunction` trait](https://github.com/othiym23/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L28). Note that both are abstract. If you write a function, you're responsible for determining what `apply` does. If you write a partial function, you're responsible for determining where it's defined.

`isDefinedAt` will often get magicked away by the compiler if you use partial function syntax. So if we write

```
val f: PartialFunction[Option[Int], Int] = { case Some(x) => x }
```

Then we can do

```
f.isDefinedAt(None) // false
f.isDefinedAt(Some(1)) // true
```

---

EDIT: Based on your comment, you're confused by `PartialFunction.this.apply`. Note the context in which this is executed.

```
new PartialFunction[A1, B1] {
    def isDefinedAt(x: A1): Boolean = 
      PartialFunction.this.isDefinedAt(x) || that.isDefinedAt(x)
    def apply(x: A1): B1 = 
      if (PartialFunction.this.isDefinedAt(x)) PartialFunction.this.apply(x) 
      else that.apply(x)
  }
```

We're inside of a new anonymous object. `this` refers to that anonymous object. If we implemented `apply` in terms of `this.apply`, then it would be infinite recursion. Think of `PartialFunction.this` as being kind of like `super`, but rather than calling the superclass method, we're calling the concrete class method from inside of an anonymous instance.

Comment: Thanks Silvio for your explanation and valuable time!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's `Function1` since PartialFunction extends `A => B` https://github.com/othiym23/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Function1.scala

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am confused about the prior words.. PartialFunction.this.